# Apache server file permissions and url accessibility

Tags: php, apache2, chmod

Is it possible to arrange file permissions/group ownership/etc in such a way that a file can be read by the function `readFile()` for a forced download, but it cannot be downloaded by navigating to the literal url of the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could add the user that is running apache / php to the group that owns the file. And set config to read and write for owner and owner group, and no permission at all for others. (-rwxrw---- 0r 0760)

Never tested it, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The Apache user will need `read` permissions. To prevent it from being navigated to, the best (and easiest) solution is to store the file outside of the web folder.